# antlr4 matches longest one

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I try an Antlr4 grammar file. When I change define of ID property

```
ID :[A-Z]+;
```

to

```
ID: [A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
```

I got this error.

> line 1:7 mismatched input 'E550' expecting {'W', 'I'}
>
> line 1:12 mismatched input ';' expecting {'W', 'I'}

Actualy I know the reason. which mathces with the longest one. But I must use ID Like erroneous way. and my foo must be E or I and Number. How can I make it happen? any help is appreciate.

Here is my code snippet which causes the error.

```
QUEST E550 ;
```

Here is my grammar

```
grammar test;

block: foo+;
foo:ID op=(WARNING|INFORMATION)INT SCOL;
SCOL :';';
WARNING :'W';
INFORMATION :'I';
ID: [A-Z]+ ;
//if I change to ID: [A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]* ; error occurs
INT : [0-9]+;
SPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
OTHER: . ;
```

Comment: `QUEST E550 ;` cannot be parsed by the grammar you posted. But I can make an educated guess you forgot to add `ERROR : 'E';` to the example grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ID` rule cannot start with `W`, `I` or `E`, then you will need to exclude those from the start:

```
ID: [A-DF-HJ-VX-Z] [A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
```

Of course, then input like `EEEEE` will not become an `ID`. To account for such cases, you could (1) let your `ID` rule start with a single uppercase other than `W`, `I` or `E` followed by the rest, or (2) let it start with 2 letters followed by the rest:

```
ID
 : [A-DF-HJ-VX-Z] [A-Za-z0-9_]* // (1)
 | [A-Z] [A-Z] [A-Za-z0-9_]*    // (2) 
 ;
```